# Cannot share large object between processes with queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In python, I have some large objects (pandas dataframe, to be specific) that needs to be transferred from a child process to the main process using multiprocessing module. Everything works fine when the object has size of about 1Gb in memory. However, then the object becomes as large as 5Gb, the child process just disappears along with its memory usage after the main process "get" the object from the queue, and the main process never gets the object as shown by the memory usage. Is this a bug of Python? Is there any solution around it?

Comment: huh weird.  What if you break up your data frame -- stream it as rows or something -- and recreate it on the other side, do you still get the same problem?

Comment: can you add some code? How do you share the objects? Are you only using queue? or are you working with a manager?